# Queue Machanism in .NET and SQL Server

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql-server, msmq, message-queue

I have an ASP.NET web application that sends long process request to sql server. We want to change that, and instead send web request to a queue, a Windows Services pop message from the queue, and send it one by one to sql server. Currently, we need to decide what machanism is used to for the queue.

A few options to implement the queue being considered, as below:

1) A database table to simulate a queue, or

2) Windows Message queue

I want to find out **the pros and cons of using windows MSMQ, and database table.**

**Update**:

Other solution

Service Broker: suggested by Remus Rusanu

It requires deep learning curve. Perfmonece remains unknown.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to mix MSMQ or WCF in, just use the SQL Server built-in queuing capabilities. See [Asynchronous procedure execution](http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/) for an example. This way you do not need a new process to dequeue MSMQ requests and process the DB long calls, you do not have to deal with separate message store and DB strore, you have one coherent back-restore for both messages and data, your messages fail over together with the data in case of High Availability situation. Not to mention that SQL Server queues scale to significantly higher margins than MSMQ (both in throughput and capacity). Using MSMQ would require you to provide a solution for all these problems: consistent backup/restore, fail over the MSMQ together with the database in case of HA incident, provide a process to read the MSMQ messages and do the DB work.

Comment: @Remus Rusanu, thanks. It sounds a good solution. I will have a read, and come back to vote it as answer if it is suitable.

Comment: @@Remus Rusanu, will database trigger be able to insert message into the queue?

Comment: Yes, a table trigger can do it

Comment: @Remus Rusanu is it Service Broker you are referring to? Am I right that service broker is a big topic to learn, setup, and develop. The performance of it is not good. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It is Service Broker. Agree that is a big thing to learn, but I would disagree that performance is not too good.

Comment: If you want to stay on more beaten path, then http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/, but you loose Activation (you'll need a process to monitor for changes, poll basically). Otherwise, MSMQ.

Comment: @Remus Rusanu Thanks. Is there good book or link (beginner) on service broker you can recommend, in addition to that link earlier?

Comment: This is a good book: http://www.amazon.com/Server-Service-Broker-Books-Professionals/dp/1590599993 (I contributed chapter 12 in it). My site has many more articles http://rusanu.com/articles/ (I used to work in the Service Broker team)

Comment: @Remus Rusanu Great book. I will buy one. One more question, will service broker support the following scenario: Once a message is pushed into the db queue, one manager thread pops the message off the queue, and spawn off other thread to process the required work. Once the child thread finishes the work, it can signal the manager thread its status. The manager thread acts as controller, which assigns work to its children thread.

Comment: The problem you ask (delegating work to a subthread) is actually quite complex, irrelevant of the solution (MSMQ, tables as queues, SSB). The issue is that you have a transaction doing the dequeue followed by a long operation (the fact that work is done by child-threads is irrelevant). If the dequeue transaction is not committed while the long work is done, then you get all the bad things that occur with long transactions. The usual trick is to set a timer and commit, then reset the timer on end of work. If the system crashes in the middle of the long work, the timer will re-schedule the work

Comment: SSB has support for such persistent, transactional timers, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187804.aspx.

Comment: But note that you don't need a controller thread and sub threads. SSB activation has some 'magic sauce'. It has capability to start processing threads on-demand (see `max_queue_readers` in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189529.aspx) and also some special locking capabilities, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171615.aspx. SSB Activation can also be used to launch a process, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_service_broker/archive/2008/11/21/announcing-service-broker-external-activator.aspx

Comment: no need to mix msmq/wcf in if you want code thats 30 times more complex. After reviewing that site - I still would vote msmq/wcf. Its simple, highly available, and can replace your service (plus can get hosted in iis... or not)

Answer (score 3):

A database table will require polling to check for database changes, unless you can devise some clever thing using triggers.  MSMQ will not, so it wins on efficiency.

A queue can guarantee delivery, even if the consuming database is down.  A database table cannot.

I'll bet that a database table is more familiar to you.  MSMQ is new technology, which always carries some risk.

Setting up a queue means another moving part in your application; that can add complexity.

I think there could be a third way: a threaded queue data structure with producers/consumers.  Have a look at .NET classes to see if something like that exists.  Perhaps the multi-threaded capabilities in .NET can give you the asynchronous processing you need with less complexity that MSMQ.

Comment: @duffymo the polling is required when either MSMQ or database table is used.

Comment: No need to poll with SQL Server based queues, they have built-in Activation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171617.aspx

Comment: I assumed that there'd be an event-based model for MSMQ like the one used by Java JMS.  I'm incorrect about that.

Comment: There is an event drive MSMQ model, see MSMQ Activation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752246.aspx, requires IIS 7.0 and Windows Activation Process Service http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789006.aspx

Comment: @duffymo "MSMQ is new technology" Are you kidding? MSMQ was available for Windows 95!

Comment: @john - I believe he meant its new tech for them to learn.. not that its new technology.

Answer (score 1):

Use MSMQ implementation via WCF. Its simple - incredibly easy to setup and handles the receiver code being down as well.

Calling from Asp.Net is then trivial.

See: (and others)
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/skaufman/archive/2008/02/20/processing-multiple-queues-in-fifo-order-with-wcf.aspx

Comment: MSMQ in WCF has more overhead, and is overkill.

Comment: That's like saying asp.net is overkill to serve up a simple document. I respectfully disagree - its almost no time to get it running - its highly available - not to mention wcf runs on sites with unbelievably high transaction rates - meaningful overhead here is debatable. The advantage here is your service can go away - anyways.. just an idea. we run it with great success. What transactional volume are you looking at?

Comment: I think MSMQ would be more suitable than MSMQ in WCF for my scenario, if I have to pick between MSQM and MSMQ in WCF. However, the post is about database table queue vs MSMQ.

Comment: your post was about asp.net and a queue as well. Your calls to WCF basically act as your interface to your queue but easier to setup since you are coding against another method that sits on top of your queue. Simply set your thread count to 1 and you have your FIFO queue - thats it. no other code required.   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/63aa7d1c-8870-4fc0-9cc3-30418473e5fb/